# How to get value from Json Object ...?

Tags: java, json

How do you get a value from a json object, if `JsonArray` type is 'Personal'? I would like a a name value pair like this:

```
String s = "February" ;
int i = 3;
```

I would really appreciate some advice on how to proceed further.

Thanks in advance,
Sankar

```
String monthArray[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
            "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",
            "December" };

    System.out.println("Size of month array:-->> " + monthArray.length);

    JSONObject jbj = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jbj1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jbj2 = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject general = new JSONObject();

    JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray jarray1 = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray jarray2 = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject finalGen = new JSONObject();

    jbj.put("February", 3);
    jbj.put("March", 15);
    jbj.put("April", 6);
    jbj.put("July", 10);
    jbj.put("December", 5);

    jbj1.put("February", 3);
    jbj1.put("March", 14);
    jbj1.put("April", 23);
    jbj1.put("May", 6);

    jbj2.put("February", 33);
    jbj2.put("March", 12);
    jbj2.put("May", 4);
    jbj2.put("June", 7);

    jarray.add(jbj);
    jarray1.add(jbj1);
    jarray2.add(jbj2);

    general.put("Personal", jarray);
    general.put("Common", jarray1);
    general.put("Management", jarray2);
    finalGen.put("FinalResultSet", general);

    System.out.println("\n Personal Value :-->> " + finalGen.toString(3));

    JSONObject finalson = JSONObject.fromObject(finalGen
            .get("FinalResultSet"));
    JSONArray jarra = finalson.getJSONArray("Personal");

    for (int i = 0; i < jarra.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject jb = jarra.getJSONObject(i);

        for (int p = 0; p < monthArray.length; p++) {

            String s = monthArray[p];

            System.out.println("\n VALUE OF STR " + s);
            String t = jb.getString(s);

            System.out.println("\n  VALUE OF STR Json Str " + t);

        }
    }

    System.out.println("Personal String " + jarra);

}
```

### My output:-

```
Size of month array:-->> 12

Personal Value :-->> {"FinalResultSet": {
    "Personal": [   {
      "February": 3,
      "March": 15,
      "April": 6,
      "July": 10,
      "December": 5
   }],
   "Common": [   {
      "February": 3,
      "March": 14,
      "April": 23,
      "May": 6
   }],
   "Management": [   {
      "February": 33,
      "March": 12,
      "May": 4,
      "June": 7
   }]
}}

VALUE OF STR January
```

### Exception:-

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["January"] not found.
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:2177)
    at JFreechartDemo.XMLData.main(XMLData.java:68)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get value of field with key "January" inside your `for` loop, but there is no such field.
You should first put key-value pair like that into your JSON object.

Have a look at JSONObject `get` method documentation. There is something like that there:

```
Throws:
JSONException - if the key is not found.
```

Because get method throws exception if there is no key it's not a really good idea to iterate through the whole array with months and trying to guess if the specific month is inside JSON as a key. You can do it if you want, but you should use `has` method first to verify if month really exists.

On the other hand you can get all names of the keys from JSONObject and then call `get` method only on those names.

Comment: If i put a Key as January means then it shows as JSONObject["February"] not found.Anyway i am looping the Month array , from there if any of the  key-value pair matches means then its prints the key value pair ,but in my cases i have so many key value pair ...for that condition what to do ..?

Comment: put an if(jb.has(s) ) before String t = jb.getString(s);, ie check if the key is present in the array.

Comment: also make sure that you iterate on the proper level of your JSON file, because it looks like you iterate on the array with 3 elements Personal, Common, Management and you think you are inside one of these.

Comment: Object key =  jb.get(s) ;    if(key!=null){
String value = key.toString() ;     System.out.println(" Key :-- " + s +" Value :-- " + value);
if(key.equals(s)){ String t = jb.getString(s);
System.out.println("2222Value is present :-->> " + t); 
     }
 }

Comment: Finally i got a key value pair ,you said before looping use 'has' method to verify but how to use 'has' method

Comment: Instead of this: String t = jb.getString(s) you should use: if(jb.has(s)) {
              String t = jb.getString(s);
             }

Comment: Ok Finally i got a key value-pair, changed the code and tried has method it working fine. Thanks for your great help .

Comment: Thanks Jakub Hr and ray for your valuable time .Its working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
private void doLogin(String userName, String password) {

    //http://obbg.in/api/login.php?action=login&username=tejal+patel+&password=ZGhhcmE5ODk4MjQ4Mzg3%0A

    byte[] data = new byte[0];
    try {
        data = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        password = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Ion.with(this)
                .load("http://obbg.in/api/login.php")
                .setBodyParameter("action", "login")
                .setBodyParameter("username", URLEncoder.encode(userName, "utf-8"))
                .setBodyParameter("password", password)
                .asString()
                .setCallback(this);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray username = jsonObject.optJSONArray("Result");



        etLoginPassword.setText("");
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```